# Docker fails to start splunk container when NFS volume is mounted

Tags: docker, splunk, nfs, synology, cifs

Fighting with getting splunk to run in docker on photonOS system.

I'm mounting /opt/splunk/etc and /opt/splunk/var as nfs volumes and the ansible installation process built into the docker image fails when it tries to change the ownership of the /opt/splunk/etc folder.

```
2023-06-07T22:50:23.959798220Z TASK [splunk_common : Update Splunk directory owner] ***************************
2023-06-07T22:50:23.960519384Z fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
2023-06-07T22:50:23.960528648Z     "changed": false,
2023-06-07T22:50:23.960534086Z     "gid": 999,
2023-06-07T22:50:23.960539096Z     "group": "ansible",
2023-06-07T22:50:23.960544285Z     "mode": "0777",
2023-06-07T22:50:23.960562227Z     "owner": "ansible",
2023-06-07T22:50:23.960567851Z     "path": "/opt/splunk/etc",
2023-06-07T22:50:23.960572882Z     "size": 0,
2023-06-07T22:50:23.960577824Z     "state": "directory",
2023-06-07T22:50:23.960582803Z     "uid": 999
2023-06-07T22:50:23.960587710Z }
2023-06-07T22:50:23.960597501Z MSG:
2023-06-07T22:50:23.960602388Z 
2023-06-07T22:50:23.960620964Z chown failed: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: b'/opt/splunk/etc'
```

By default the volume mounts as root so I've tried to chown'd the nfs source folders to the UID:GID to match the splunk:splunk and ansible:ansible users and I can see in the container that the volumes mount correctly with these user permissions. However the above error persists.

```
jeff@photon-machine [ ~ ]$ docker container exec splunk ls -l /opt/splunk 
total 3052
...snip...
drwxrwxrwx 1 splunk splunk       0 Jun  7 21:58 etc
...snip...
drwxrwxrwx 1 splunk splunk       0 Jun  7 21:58 var
```

Ugh...

Jeff

Here's the details of the setup:
Docker running in PhotonOS, leveraging NFSv4 and CIFv3 shares hosted on Synology NAS.

```
Jeff@diskstation:~$ uname -a
Linux diskstation 3.10.108 #42962 SMP Fri Mar 24 00:28:41 CST 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux synology_avoton_415+

jeff@photon-machine [ ~ ]$ uname -a
Linux photon-machine 5.10.168-2.ph4-esx #1-photon SMP Thu Mar 2 03:44:00 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux

jeff@photon-machine [ ~ ]$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086

jeff@photon-machine [ ~ ]$ docker inspect splunk
[
    {
        "Id": "0c30a3224f353ea998d3e756175712b3e7b9969ad3daa76bf3cd7f3565c0ded1",
        "Created": "2023-06-07T01:28:19.766822084Z",
        "Path": "/sbin/entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "start-service"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 255,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2023-06-07T01:51:04.731635988Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2023-06-07T04:49:44.961296555Z",
            "Health": {
                "Status": "unhealthy",
                "FailingStreak": 20,
                "Log": [
                    {
                        "Start": "2023-06-07T04:40:17.518101926Z",
                        "End": "2023-06-07T04:40:48.394343685Z",
                        "ExitCode": -1,
                        "Output": "Health check exceeded timeout (30s)"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2023-06-07T04:41:27.585164745Z",
                        "End": "2023-06-07T04:42:03.530697274Z",
                        "ExitCode": -1,
                        "Output": "Health check exceeded timeout (30s)"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2023-06-07T04:42:57.966912236Z",
                        "End": "2023-06-07T04:44:38.672315024Z",
                        "ExitCode": -1,
                        "Output": "Health check exceeded timeout (30s)"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2023-06-07T04:45:14.428014408Z",
                        "End": "2023-06-07T04:45:45.98340735Z",
                        "ExitCode": -1,
                        "Output": "Health check exceeded timeout (30s)"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2023-06-07T04:46:33.825896157Z",
                        "End": "2023-06-07T04:46:34.426481881Z",
                        "ExitCode": 137,
                        "Output": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Image": "sha256:04b6d9d4490c5af5b901896920b73fb33537bb82a3ee16927f479456199b19b1",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0c30a3224f353ea998d3e756175712b3e7b9969ad3daa76bf3cd7f3565c0ded1/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0c30a3224f353ea998d3e756175712b3e7b9969ad3daa76bf3cd7f3565c0ded1/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0c30a3224f353ea998d3e756175712b3e7b9969ad3daa76bf3cd7f3565c0ded1/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0c30a3224f353ea998d3e756175712b3e7b9969ad3daa76bf3cd7f3565c0ded1/0c30a3224f353ea998d3e756175712b3e7b9969ad3daa76bf3cd7f3565c0ded1-json.log",
        "Name": "/splunk",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "splunk_var_cif:/opt/splunk/var",
                "splunk_etc_cif:/opt/splunk/etc"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "bridge",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": [
                "AUDIT_WRITE",
                "CHOWN",
                "DAC_OVERRIDE",
                "FOWNER",
                "FSETID",
                "KILL",
                "MKNOD",
                "NET_BIND_SERVICE",
                "NET_RAW",
                "SETFCAP",
                "SETGID",
                "SETPCAP",
                "SETUID",
                "SYS_CHROOT"
            ],
            "CapDrop": [
                "AUDIT_CONTROL",
                "BLOCK_SUSPEND",
                "DAC_READ_SEARCH",
                "IPC_LOCK",
                "IPC_OWNER",
                "LEASE",
                "LINUX_IMMUTABLE",
                "MAC_ADMIN",
                "MAC_OVERRIDE",
                "NET_ADMIN",
                "NET_BROADCAST",
                "SYSLOG",
                "SYS_ADMIN",
                "SYS_BOOT",
                "SYS_MODULE",
                "SYS_NICE",
                "SYS_PACCT",
                "SYS_PTRACE",
                "SYS_RAWIO",
                "SYS_RESOURCE",
                "SYS_TIME",
                "SYS_TTY_CONFIG",
                "WAKE_ALARM"
            ],
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": [],
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": true,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": [],
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ],
            "Init": false
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1c87ea8979fed2b10ca39669fdb7e9c528c08c73cca41ae98aec7a16ee0171c9-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8f05a00f757925e42612483444171bc331f29a2b16dfbd7dd24d77da90a239b3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/22ef39100ae8b649da3861d3436bfc13242bef6b40015fe3f04ec4577447fe69/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9ee62e22b056d50c75ea1216f08b8b47ed51a03976e44aea05af305d0f9587f6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dab8f18053315fddc60ddb28f67ed33cdbc39095a3e9179fc7a1e42d0ca4ddc2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1fdcff861cd8066ffad875ffa4c062369d2d053b41aca1d4506695448a4508a0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/61de3e442a14b7495e31aa260df899781f451706173aae9fec28b0121db0c7cf/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/022df818fa54be0ff80efe6aeb9a6afb8439f9ec5d68bc58a3a9d4480fdd5755/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5cdd113b3166943d0a6e75b78c633e9358c8e9d078e3dc98ad38114f8e7af7d8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0d9a5942db333802c68aff909b9fb275ed884a61741fd487feebbe5494bd711a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/581f3da760a2700c6de684784dfc93335533fdd771bc46cf26f4ddafcf620365/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9bd76717063684dbd16bfbb23461b9859087d3115ac06659bd157b391f926fbd/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1c87ea8979fed2b10ca39669fdb7e9c528c08c73cca41ae98aec7a16ee0171c9/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1c87ea8979fed2b10ca39669fdb7e9c528c08c73cca41ae98aec7a16ee0171c9/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1c87ea8979fed2b10ca39669fdb7e9c528c08c73cca41ae98aec7a16ee0171c9/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "splunk_var_cif",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/splunk_var_cif/_data",
                "Destination": "/opt/splunk/var",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "splunk_etc_cif",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/splunk_etc_cif/_data",
                "Destination": "/opt/splunk/etc",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "99127cc0ce43",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "ansible",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8000/tcp": {},
                "8065/tcp": {},
                "8088/tcp": {},
                "8089/tcp": {},
                "8191/tcp": {},
                "9887/tcp": {},
                "9997/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "SPLUNK_PASSWORD=REDACTED",
                "SPLUNK_START_ARGS=--accept-license",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "container=oci",
                "BUSYBOX_URL=",
                "PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.16",
                "PYTHON_GPG_KEY_ID=0D96DF4D4110E5C43FBFB17F2D347EA6AA65421D",
                "SPLUNK_HOME=/opt/splunk",
                "SPLUNK_GROUP=splunk",
                "SPLUNK_USER=splunk",
                "TMPSPLUNKDIR=/opt/splunk/tmp",
                "TMPETCDIR=/opt/splunk/tmp/etc",
                "SPLUNK_ROLE=splunk_standalone",
                "SPLUNK_DEFAULTS_URL=",
                "SPLUNK_ANSIBLE_HOME=/opt/ansible",
                "ANSIBLE_USER=ansible",
                "ANSIBLE_GROUP=ansible",
                "CONTAINER_ARTIFACT_DIR=/opt/container_artifact"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "start-service"
            ],
            "Healthcheck": {
                "Test": [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "/sbin/checkstate.sh || exit 1"
                ],
                "Interval": 30000000000,
                "Timeout": 30000000000,
                "StartPeriod": 180000000000,
                "Retries": 5
            },
            "Image": "splunk/splunk:latest",
            "Volumes": {
                "/opt/splunk/etc": {},
                "/opt/splunk/var": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/opt/splunk",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/sbin/entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "architecture": "x86_64",
                "build-date": "2023-05-03T15:02:09",
                "com.redhat.component": "ubi8-minimal-container",
                "com.redhat.license_terms": "https://www.redhat.com/en/about/red-hat-end-user-license-agreements#UBI",
                "description": "Splunk Enterprise is a platform for operational intelligence. Our software lets you collect, analyze, and act upon the untapped value of big data that your technology infrastructure, security systems, and business applications generate. It gives you insights to drive operational performance and business results.",
                "distribution-scope": "public",
                "io.buildah.version": "1.27.3",
                "io.k8s.description": "The Universal Base Image Minimal is a stripped down image that uses microdnf as a package manager. This base image is freely redistributable, but Red Hat only supports Red Hat technologies through subscriptions for Red Hat products. This image is maintained by Red Hat and updated regularly.",
                "io.k8s.display-name": "Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 Minimal",
                "io.openshift.expose-services": "",
                "io.openshift.tags": "minimal rhel8",
                "maintainer": "support@splunk.com",
                "name": "splunk",
                "release": "1",
                "summary": "UBI 8 Docker image of Splunk Enterprise",
                "url": "https://access.redhat.com/containers/#/registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8-minimal/images/8.8-860",
                "vcs-ref": "dee8029ddcc7ecbfbebb0905d2b15e134338616c",
                "vcs-type": "git",
                "vendor": "splunk",
                "version": "9.0.5"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "9b657058a56ad136dcd067cb165beab924d7ff88a4e29951b51cc9602d917997",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "49810"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "49810"
                    }
                ],
                "8065/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "49809"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "49809"
                    }
                ],
                "8088/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "49808"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "49808"
                    }
                ],
                "8089/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "49807"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "49807"
                    }
                ],
                "8191/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "49806"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "49806"
                    }
                ],
                "9887/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "49805"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "49805"
                    }
                ],
                "9997/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "49804"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "49804"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/9b657058a56a",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "06508cd155fb478ea8c644db3620285695c5da0c350b1f8500f7b4510b01a4ec",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.5",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {},
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "60b3d4ca9cf390ae7f2d59922000b8233be3a1baa1987301b040b76751113ba3",
                    "EndpointID": "06508cd155fb478ea8c644db3620285695c5da0c350b1f8500f7b4510b01a4ec",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.5",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```